# How to recover ownership of private repo whose old owner was removed from the organization

Tags: github

Following is the problem I have:
User A joined our organization and created a private repository. This user A was then removed from our organization but the repository he created wasn't transferred to anyone. Now we want to add more collaborators to this repo but we can't since the old owner is gone. Is there a way we can do that? Also can we change the ownership of the repository?

Comment: I would recommend talking to GitHub support about that, I think they can help.

Comment: Thanks, just contacted them with my problem.

Comment: have you tried this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/change-or-transfer-repository-ownership-289964397.html)